# How to resize the Google noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

How i can resize height and width for Google reCAPTCHA controls without using css attributes ?

transform
-webkit-transform ,
transform-origin ,
-webkit-transform-origin ,

Thank you All

Comment: what you mean by *css attributes*?

Comment: @TemaniAfif : i mean resize the controls without using transform -webkit-transform , transform-origin , -webkit-transform-origin ,

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same question, the transform pack is **visual** and don't make the dom changes, I mean ...

[image: Test example]

This is what i need: Recaptcha and button in the bottom.

[image]

But, when i apply the transform, the recaptcha use the same space but with blank space, so, I try to make a version with the same height but minus width and works only in the Firefox Developer Tool, because the recaptcha is a iFrame, and worst than that, it's restricted, so, you can't access with js.

My solution is to back to the traditional and universal solution **BUT** with different positions depending the page and **works**.

```css
.g-recaptcha{-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 50%;}
#index .g-recaptcha{-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;transform-origin:0 100%;}
```

[image]
[image]

I hope this reply can resolve your problem.
Greetings,

Answer (score -2):

you may find solution here
https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/

HTML:

```
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<div align="center">
<div class="container">
<p>Edit JS var reCaptchaWidth <br>to the size you need</p>
&nbsp;    
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data- 
sitekey="6Le53RUUAAAAAGyChlQ0QhnPO8FXEFRzskMCofVR"></div>
</form>

<!--CTA -->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a class="btn" href="#" style="float: center;"><strong>SUBMIT</strong></a>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I say in Question i don't need ( transform -webkit-transform , transform-origin , -webkit-transform-origin)